# Azure Mobile Service "Cannot insert if the id member is already set."

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, azure-mobile-services

I am building an Azure Mobile Service and am attempting to use Entity Framework Code First.  I am having my database entities inherit from the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.EntityData` class which includes an `Id` string property as the primary key.  I want to be able to pass a value for the `Id` on an insert, but I get the response `"Cannot insert if the id member is already set."`  If I do not pass a value for the `Id`, the insert is successful and the row has a GUID `Id` value.

I have tried using fluentAPI to specify that the `Id` column on this table is not to be generated by the database in the OnModelCreating method of the DbContext:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

I have also tried the attribute decoration way, by rebuilding the `DataEntity` class as I needed it without any luck

```
public class User : ITableData
{

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Index(IsClustered = true)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.CreatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Deleted)]
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Id)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.UpdatedAt)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }
    [TableColumn(TableColumnType.Version)]
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testing the service directly I was able to insert `Id`s without a problem, so it turns out this was not an EF problem.  The problem was the case sensitivity of the Azure Mobile Service Javascript client.  Inserting with a specified value for the `Id` will only work if the JSON parameter for Id == 'id'.  After dropping Id to all lowercase, everything is peachy.

If nothing else, I hope this saves someone some time someday.

Answer (score 2):

@DevNoob, thanks for your investigation. I have filed an issue to track this bug: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/issues/96